# CSS Hover div affect other div won't work on google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover

i creating a website and I have problem with hover effect. I have 3 div elements on start page, I want to make transparent two other div's when hovering a one of this three div's. In Mozilla Firefox everything works excellent, but on Google Chrome it won't work (any element doesn't apply opacity). This is website on temporary address - http://letsdrink.fm4.pl/

This is my code for hovering this elements:

```
#center:hover a {
    opacity:0.2;
}

#center:hover a:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
#center:hover a:hover .start-element-more {
    background:#8f1fe7;
}
```

And part of code

```
<div id="center">
<a href="Serwis-Kawowy">
<div id="start-element">Serwis kawowy
<div class="start-element-more">+ czytaj więcej</div>
</div></a> 
<a href="Obsluga-Barmanska">
<div id="start-element2">
Obsluga Barmanska
<div class="start-element-more">+ czytaj więcej</div>
</div></a> 
<a href="Kursy-Szkolenia">
<div id="start-element3">Kursy i szkolenia
<div class="start-element-more">+ czytaj więcej</div>
</div></a>
</div>
```

You can check this on firefox and chrome - on firefox everything works well.

Comment: here's something you can improve in your question, format your html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#center:hover a,
#center:hover a >div {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
#center:hover a:hover,
#center:hover a > div:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Your Fix:

```
#center:hover a,
#center:hover a > div {
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Comment: It works, but then every div in #center div have opacity 0.2 - I wan't a hovered div don't have a opacity - for this I have a this part of css:
    `#center:hover a:hover {
        opacity:1;
    }`
But with your code then every div have opacity.